# How to use the Transformation matrix for 2 x 3 or 3 x 2 matrices?

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation, rotation

I have two matrices in a given axes ($K_1 \:\&\: K_2$) and their dimensions are ($2\times 3\:\:\:\&\:\:\:3\times 2$) respectively, now the axes were rotated by an angle $\theta$, the values of ($K_1 \:\&\: K_2$) in the new axes must be changed.
for ($2\times2$) matrix, it is easy to use the transfer matrix $A$,$$A=\pmatrix{\:\:\:\cos\theta &\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta}$$ and by using the relation below the new $K$ matrix can be found:$$K' = A^T K A$$

My question is, how can I apply the above procedure for $K_1 \:\&\: K_2$?

Comment: This is not possible with the specific matrix dimensions you provided due to matrix multiplication rules.

Comment: @J_Nat I know so I ask, is there any way to modify the $A$ matrix to be $2\times3$ or $3\times2$?

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho the link is not found it said `Oops, the page you're looking for can't be found.`

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationMatrix.html?q=RotationMatrix

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool You should try to be more straight forward with what you are asking in the future. I interpreted your question as you just wanted a function using the A and K's you gave.

Comment: As far as I can see in the properties of the rotation matrix: first of all "A rotation matrix is orthogonal, i.e. the inverse is equal to the transpose" so as @J_Nat said it is not possible to apply it for $K_1 \& K_2$, what can I do now, if I want to rotate these matrices, i.e. is there any other method to do that?

Comment: @J_Nat I want to use a function to do the rotation (contains the $A$ matrix) to rotate the $K$'s matrices.

Comment: What axis do you want to rotate `K1` around?

Comment: @Feyre I want to rotate $K_1$ about the `z-axis`.

Comment: One approach would be to embed the K1 and K2 in 3D space (i.e., as 3 by 3 matrices) and do the rotation there. Then chop off the unneeded dimensions.

Comment: Have you seen `RotationMatrix[\[Theta]];and RotationMatrix[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}];`?

Comment: @Feyre No, I don't, I'm a new user in Mathematica, so I'll try it.

Comment: @bills this suggestion sound good, but the problem is for `2D` the $K_1$ matrix is $2\times3$, in `3D` it will be `3\times4`. I wonder if there is a way to modify the $A$ matrix so it can be applied for $2\times3$ or $3\times2$ matrices?

Comment: In the usuall $2\times2$ matrix case, if we add a third column of $$\matrix{0\\0\\1}$$ then by using the $3\times3$ rotation matrix, it will give the same results as if we use $2\times2$ rotation matrix (after triming the added column), so I guess by the same way for $K_1$, if we added a third row of $\matrix{0&0&1}$ and use the $3\times3$ rotation matrix it will rotate it. Who agree with me??